# AS3 - How to properly escape regex

Tags: regex, actionscript-3, syntax

I've got a couple of regex's in AS3 that are defined with the inline AS3 regex syntax like:

- `/\/\*[\s\S]*?\*\//gm`

I want to convert that to the AS3 RegEx class constructor like:

- `new RegExp('/\/\*[\s\S]*?\*\//', "gm")`

I'm not sure if I have to escape the backslashes or not. Do you know how to convert it?

---

```
    /**  ------------------------- Regular Expressions ---------------------------- */

    public static var multiLineCComments:RegExp     = /\/\*[\s\S]*?\*\//gm;
    public static var singleLineCComments:RegExp        = /\/\/.*$/gm;
    public static var singleLinePerlComments:RegExp = /#.*$/gm;
    public static var doubleQuotedString:RegExp     = /"([^\\"\n]|\\.)*"/g;
    public static var singleQuotedString:RegExp     = /'([^\\'\n]|\\.)*'/g;
    public static var multiLineDoubleQuotedString:XRegExp   = new XRegExp('"([^\\\\"]|\\\\.)*"', 'gs');
    public static var multiLineSingleQuotedString:XRegExp   = new XRegExp("'([^\\\\']|\\\\.)*'", 'gs');
    public static var xmlComments:RegExp                = /(&lt;|<)!--[\s\S]*?--(&gt;|>)/gm;
    public static var url:RegExp                        = /\w+:\/\/[\w-.\/?%&=:@;]*/g;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understood how to do it.

1. Delete the first and last `/` which is the part of the AS3 regex syntax.
2. Place the ending options such as `g` or `gm` in the 2nd argument.
3. And lastly escape every backslash  (`\`) by replacing it with 2 backslashes

So in summary:

- Inline syntax : `/\/\*[\s\S]*?\*\//gm`
- RegExp syntax : `new RegExp ("\\/\\*[\\s\\S]*?\\*\\/", 'gm')`

Answer (score 0):

You could do this another way:

```
private static const pattern:RegExp = /\/\*[\s\S]*?\*\//;
public static var regex:XRegExp = new XRegExp(pattern.source, "gm");
```